# In spring batch, all partitioned step share the same itemwriter listener?

Tags: spring-batch

I have the config like this

```
<batch:chunk writer="itemWriter" reader="itemReader" commit-interval="1000" />
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="MyWriterListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
```

I want to know after I partitioned the resources, each parallel steps are sharing the same   MyWriterListener ?

Here is the listenner

```
public class MyVehiclesWriterListener implements ItemWriteListener<PurchasedVehicleModel>, StepExecutionListener {

private static final String FILE_NAME = "fileName";

private StepExecution stepExecution;

@Override
public void beforeWrite(List<? extends PurchasedVehicleModel> items) {
    //s_logger.log(LogLevel.WARN, stepExecution.getId() + " The processed file name is " + stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getString(FILE_NAME));
}

@Override
public void afterWrite(List<? extends PurchasedVehicleModel> items) {

    log(LogLevel.WARN, " Step Id : " + stepExecution.getId());
}

@Override
public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List<? extends PurchasedVehicleModel> items) {
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution currentStepExecution) {
    log(LogLevel.WARN, " Step Id : " + currentStepExecution.getId());
    stepExecution = currentStepExecution;
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    return null;
}
```

}

In the afterWrite function, I can only get the same step execution id.

But in the beforeStep function, I can get different ids.